# Using Gauss Divergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Show that the image of the function $\phi:(0,1)\times(0,1) \to \mathbb R^3, \phi(u,v)=(u^2,u+v,v^2)^T$ is a 2-dimensional manifold $M$ in $\mathbb R^3$.

I used the following theorem:

$\emptyset \neq M \subseteq \mathbb R^p$ is a d-dimensioanl manifold iff for every $x \in M$ there is a d-dimensional embedding $\phi:C\to M$ such that $x\in \phi(C)$.

$\phi:C\to M$ is called a *d-dimensional embedding* if:

$C\subseteq \mathbb R^d$ and $\phi(C)\subseteq M$ are open.

$\phi:C \to \phi(C)$ is a homeomorphism

$\phi:C \to \mathbb R^p$ is continuously differentiable and $\nabla \phi(t)$ is injective for every $t\in C$

> Then I need to evaluate the surface integral
>
> $\int_M n(y)h(y)d\mu(y)$

where $\mu$ is the surface measure of $M$ and $h(\xi, \eta, \zeta):=(\xi,1,\eta \cdot \zeta)$

I don't know if it is easier to work with Gauss Divergence Theorem or to solve it directly because I couldn't really get any further using both. Any help is appreciated

Comment: So, these are two questions? Or did you solve the first one, to show that it is a Manifold? For the second question, did you already apply the definition to pull der integral back to 3d? Not sure how to use the Gauss Divergence Theorem here, what nice object is $M$ the boundary of?

Comment: @hal4math I solved the first one. But I don't know what you mean by applying the definition to pull the integral back to 3d

Comment: How did you define integration over manifolds?

Comment: @hal4math $\int_M f d\mu=\int_{\phi^{-1}(M)}(f\circ \phi(s))\cdot\sqrt{\det d\phi(s)^Td\phi(s)}d\lambda_d(s)$

Comment: Yes. Did you apply that yet? Notice that you can calculate $n(y)$, with $\phi$ if I am not mistaken. (Assuming $n$ is outer normal?!)

Comment: I wanted to apply it but I dont know how to find $n(y)$

Comment: You maybe now that Normal space is orthogonal to the tagent space? Do you know how to read of the tagent space in something you calculated in the first question? Do you know how to get a orthogonal vector to two other vectors in 3d?

Comment: @hal4math The normal vectors are $\pm \frac{\frac{\partial \phi(u,v)}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \phi(u,v)}{\partial v}}{\|\frac{\partial \phi(u,v)}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial \phi(u,v)}{\partial v}\|_2}$

Comment: Looks good me, yes!

Comment: @hal4math So $n(u,v)=\frac{(2v,-4uv,2u)}{\sqrt{4v^2+16u^2v^2+4u^2}}$. But how can I determine $n(u,v)h(u,v)$ when $h$ in this example is depending on 3 variables $\xi, \eta, \zeta$? This example is confusing me so much...

Comment: Since $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ both functions must depend on three variables. I assume you have the above $n$ composed with $\phi^{-1}$. Btw. do you know the result? Is a homework or did you come up with it yourself? I am not sure if the resulting integrale is computable that easily.

Comment: I was mistaken I forgot the metric factor. I can type what I did. But I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Did you check my answer by any chance?

Comment: didnt have time yet

Answer (score 1):

Okay, roughly summarizing what was also discussed in the comments:
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
I assume the function $n = \widetilde{n} \circ \phi^{-1} : M \to \R^3$ it meant as the *normal* and because this problem has nice dimensions, we can compute
$$
\widetilde{n} (u,v) = \frac{\partial_u \phi(u,v) \times \partial_v \phi(u,v)}{\|
\partial_u \phi(u,v) \times \partial_v \phi(u,v)\|}.
$$

Now, using the definition of computing those integrals over manifolds we get
$$
\int_M \langle n, h\rangle(y) d\mu(y) = \int_{(0,1)^2} \langle \widetilde{n}(u,v),h\circ  \phi (u,v)\rangle \sqrt{\text{det}\, (d\phi^T\cdot d\phi)} d\lambda_2(u,v).
$$

Plugging the following computations
$$
\langle \widetilde{n}(u,v), h(u^2,u+v,v^2) \rangle = \langle \frac{(2v,-4uv,2u)^T}{\sqrt{4u^2 + 16u^2v^2+4v^2}}, (u^2, 1, uv^2+v^3) \rangle
$$
and 
$$\sqrt{ \text{det}\,(d\phi^T\cdot d\phi)} = \sqrt{4u^2 + 16u^2v^2 + 4v^2}$$
into the above definition yields
$$
\int_{(0,1)^2} \langle \widetilde{n}(u,v),h\circ  \phi (u,v)\rangle  d\lambda_2(u,v)
=
\int_{(0,1)^2} (2vu^2 - 4uv + 2u^2v^2+2uv^3) d\lambda_2(u,v),
$$
which can be now calculated using fubini.
\